How to represent an association between two classes, but two times, in a UML diagram?
I want to represent a database for football championships. How can I represent that a class "Match" is played between two classes "Team"?

You can represent multiple associations between the same classes in a UML class diagram by drawing separate association lines, each with its distinct role names to clarify the different relationships.
classDiagram
    class Team {
        +List<Match> homeMatches
        +List<Match> awayMatches
    }

    class Match {
        +Team homeTeam
        +Team awayTeam
    }

    Team "1" --> "*" Match : homeMatches
    Team "1" --> "*" Match : awayMatches


The role names "homeMatches" and "awayMatches" distinguish the two different associations between Match and Team3. This clearly shows that:
A match involves exactly one home team and exactly one away team.
A team can participate in multiple matches as either the home or away team.
When implementing this in code, these associations would typically become attributes in the Match class.

ref:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/345395/does-uml-allow-multiple-relations-between-2-classes

This would be better without the redundant attributes on both classes (and with valid syntax for the association arrows)

This is an interesting answer that adds a difference between home and away (otherwise, one association with multiplicity of 2 would have been enough). Indeed, homeTeam, awayTeam and homeMatches, awayMatches would better be represented by roles at the end of the association (but this is tricky with plantUML) rather than attributes, even if attributes would be used for implementing the association ;-) (And thanks for quoting my answer on SE; glad that it helped)
